# Плюсование постов wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Все привет.
Нужно, что бы гости на сайте могли выставлять +1 к записям, а потом на отдельной странице выводить например 10 самых популярных постов.
Есть ли готовые решения, что бы самому не писать?

Comment: Вы уже как-то искали готовые решения, и не нашли?

Comment: Значит я криво искал, пожалуй сначала почитаю про то как пользоваться гуглом)) Спасибо.